# how to resolve the ArgumentError: argument 2: <class 'TypeError'>: wrong type in tkinter askopenfile

Tags: python, tkinter, typeerror, wand

I want to make a tkinter gui to convert pdf page into image. I tried this:

```
root = Tk()

def open_file(): 
    global file
    file = askopenfile(mode ='rb', filetypes =[('pdf files', '*.pdf')]) 
    print('Selected:', file)

def pdftoimage():
    pdf = wi(filename=file, resolution=300)
    pdfimage = pdf.convert("jpeg")
    i=1
    for img in pdfimage.sequence:
        page = wi(image=img)
        page.save(filename="file.jpg")
        i +=1

label1 = Label(root,text="Select the ")
button1 = Button(root, text="Select File",command=open_file)
button1.place(x=10,y=10)
button2 = Button(root,text="Convert pdf into image",command=pdftoimage)
button2.place(x=10,y=40)
button3 = Button(root,text="Exit",command=root.destroy)
button3.place(x=40,y=70)
root.mainloop()
```

but it gives the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "<ipython-input-4-be9660d3a6d2>", line 33, in pdftoimage
    pdf = wi(filename=file, resolution=300)
  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\wand\image.py", line 9062, in __init__
    self.read(filename=filename)
  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\wand\image.py", line 9654, in read
    r = library.MagickReadImage(self.wand, filename)
ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 2: <class 'TypeError'>: wrong type
```

As far as i can understand, this is because of the type of file in askopenfile is  *_io.BufferedReader* but wand takes *class str* type. If i am right about that then how to make wand to access the file from askopenfile function?

Comment: Change `pdf = wi(filename=file, ...)` to `pdf = wi(file=file, ...)`.

Comment: yeah it works, Thanks. But if i don't give the file name there and ask user to save the file in any location with the name he choose. Then how to do that . i tried it using asksaveasfile method. but it saves the blank image.

Comment: Use `asksaveasfilename()` instead.